# In sapper create separate backend API in Polka or Use Same Polka server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I am new to this. So please help me. I want to ask some questions about the sapper. I have to create separate backend API in Polka (express any framework) or I can use same Polka(express) for backend? Do i have to validate requests through the same polka server? (right now I am using pug template engine with express).

Answer (score 2):

A separate backend isn't required. Sapper is the backend and the frontend.

To define a backend endpoint, add a `.js` files to the `routes` folder:

```js
// src/routes/blog.js
import db from '...'

// defines a route `GET /blog`
export async function get(_req, res) {
    const posts = await db.getPosts()

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(JSON.stringify(posts))
}
```

For more information: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs/#Server_routes

Middleware can also be added by modifying `src/server.js`.

Comment: Thanks joshnuss for answer and point to the topic. I am reading that. But How express validator work in this?

Comment: To use a validator, I think you'd need to define your endpoints/handlers inside `src/server.js`

Comment: How to add the middleware to protect apis starting with **/v1** ?